# How to get posts that are related to some tags at the same time?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the query for `posts that have all of the given tags`.

I have the query for `posts that have one of the given tags`.

The query I have is:

```
select * from `blog_posts` 
    inner join `blog_post_tag` on `blog_posts`.`id` = `blog_post_tag`.`post_id` 
    where `blog_post_tag`.`tag_id` in (?, ?) 
      and `blog_posts`.`deleted_at` is null
```

For example:

```
| post_id | tag_id |
|---------+--------|
|       1 |      1 |
|       1 |      2 |
|       2 |      1 |
|       3 |      2 |
```

- For given tags `[1]`, the result should give me the posts with the ids `1` and `2`.
- For given tags `[1, 2]`, the result should give me the post with the id `1` **(not `[1, 2, 3]`)**.

Comment: @jpw Thanks, I am trying... :)

Comment: @jpw I already did...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the expected result by:

```
select * from `blog_posts` 
    inner join `blog_post_tag` on `blog_posts`.`id` = `blog_post_tag`.`post_id` 
    where `blog_post_tag`.`tag_id` in (?, ?) 
      and `blog_posts`.`deleted_at` is null 
    group by `blog_post_tag`.`post_id` 
    having COUNT(DISTINCT `blog_post_tag`.`tag_id`) = 2
```